# elFinder standalone doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, forms, elfinder

I have been looking for a solution all day, but can't seem to find it.
I'd like to use elFinder standalone, so press button -> browse for file -> update textfield with location.
Does anyone have a clue what I can do to make it work.

It looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/troex/4A9m9/ but this one doesnt work.. 
any suggestions?

```
<script src="http://elrte.org/release/elfinder/js/elfinder.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://elrte.org/release/elfinder/css/elfinder.css" media="screen">
```

```
$('#select-button').click(function(){
var f = $('<div></div>').elfinder({
    url : 'includes/elfinder/php/connector.php',
    height: 490,
    docked: false,
    dialog: { width: 400, modal: true },
    closeOnEditorCallback: true,
    editorCallback: function(url) {
        $('#fileurl').val(url);
    }  });});
<input type="text" id="fileurl" />
<div class="button" id="select-button">select file</div>
```

Comment: http://www-you.com/en/integratsiya-na-elfinder/ This is the answer